# Azure Static Web App: Add an header for each JS file

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app, azure-static-web-app-routing

I'm using Azure Static Web App to build and deploy my app.
I want to add in the `Content-Type` header with the following content: `application/javascript; charset=UTF-8`, to each JS file I serve (since all files in the `dist` folder are in JS, this souldn't be an issue).

I have this error: `Encountered an issue while validating staticwebapp.config.json: Could not read and deserialize the provided routes file.`

Here's my staticwebapp.config.json:

```json
{
    "routes": [
        {
            "route": "/dist*",
            "headers": [
                {
                    "Content-Type": "application/javascript; charset=UTF-8"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Can you please help me?
Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: If possible can you share your repo here ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can’t. Are you looking for specific logs or for the project architecture? @SirraSneha

Comment: Which JavaScript framework or library are you using for your application?

Comment: I am using PixiJS @SirraSneha. But I found a way to resolve my issue! I've added the charset in the HTML head mark. Thanks for your time (:

Comment: @cypolo It's great to hear that you were able to resolve your issue. Could you please document your solution in an answer? It would provide clarity for those encountering similar technical challenges within the community.